# python selenium - takes a lot of time when it does not find elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

my code scans a lot of internet pages with chromedriver and searches for the same element in each page with "find_elements_by_xpath"

```
Lines = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="top"]/div[contains(@style, "display: block;")]/'
                    'div[contains(@style, "display: block;")]//tbody//a[contains(@title, "Line")]')
```

When it finds, one or multiple, it works fast and good. But, when the XPath doesn't exist it runs for 6-7 seconds and then moves on.

Can I limit the search for 1 second, And if it doesn't find in a second, just move on? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please add the code where you wait for 6-7 seconds. Is there some reason why you don't just lower the wait time from 6s to 1s?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    Lines = wait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="top"]/div[contains(@style, "display: block;")]/'
                'div[contains(@style, "display: block;")]//tbody//a[contains(@title, "Line")]')))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

This should allow you to wait for 1 second until at least one element found and get the list of required WebElements or do nothing otherwise

Comment: Using `presence_*` can be dangerous in that it just means the element is in the DOM but not necessarily accessible/clickable. Also, when you use `all_elements` it wait for *all* of them, not just the first one. I've gotten myself into trouble waiting for all and finding that one or more elements that meets the locator are disabled, not visible, etc. and the wait will time out.

Comment: @JeffC, From documentation: " An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present
 on a web page.
 locator is used to find the element
 returns the list of WebElements once they are located". Also note that OP didn't mention he wants visible/clickable elements. Considering OP uses `find_elements_..()` that also doesn't return visible/clickable elements there is nothing to worry about :)

Comment: That may be what the document states but it is misleading because I interpreted it the same way. Create a page with 5 elements that all match a locator and make one of them invisible and run a wait. It will time out because it found the 5th but it never becomes visible. It's not really "at least one"... it's "all that are located." Granted but most people don't look for A tags and then never click them... :).

Comment: @JeffC, If OP checks each page for specific anchors, I guess he might just collect the URLs (`href` attribute values), and so there is no need in visible or clickable element... IMHO :) As for `presence_of_all_elements_located`: usually it used to get the list of similar elements, e.g. options from `select` or from `ul`- it should work well, but  there is no sense to use it to get, for example, all elements that contains specific text (`//*[contains(., "text")]`)- in most cases it won't return desired output...

Comment: @JeffC, BTW, I tried to create source with several anchors, set `hidden` attribute to one of them and... got the list of all of them using `presence_of_all_elements_located` :)

Comment: Right, presence always works because it's just in the DOM. You get into trouble when you wait for clickable/visible because I was expecting (and the docs read) that only some would have to qualify... but all do.

Comment: hey, it looks useful but I tried to add this, and it is still the same as before. Maybe it does'nt what I meant